# feathers-client primus not found

Tags: ecmascript-6, feathersjs

I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: _feathersClient2.default.primus is not a function`

My code is as follows, I am using using ES6 with babel as the compiler.

```
import feathers from 'feathers-client';


const app = feathers().configure(feathers.primus({
  transformer: 'sockjs',
  pathname: '/primus',
}));

const locationService = app.service('location');
```

Comment: This was a bug in version 0.3.0 - 0.3.2. I just verified that it is fixed in 0.3.3. Making sure that version (or later) is installed should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be an error in feathers-client. I've created [an issue](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-client/issues/14) so feel free to follow along over there.

Comment: This issue has not been fixed.